# Determine if instance is a part of some AutoScaling Group in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

Is it possible to determine from instance if it's a member of AutoScaling Group in AWS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the Instance Details in the EC2 Management Console web UI, look for the Tag with the key `aws:autoscaling:groupName`. 
While not the specific question you asked, others may find this helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can run [this command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/describe-auto-scaling-instances.html) on an EC2 Linux instance to check if the current instance is in an AutoScaling group. You will need to check if the returned value is empty to determine if it is in an AutoScaling group or not.

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-instances --instance-ids `curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id 2>&1`
```

Note, you will have to have the [AWS CLI tool](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) installed and configured before you can run this command.

Answer (score 0):

Install AWS CLI on the instance and run this command: `aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-instances`

You can query the instance meta-data and compare the instance-id you have received from the previous command to check if the instance is part of autoscaling group.

To query instance-meta data, try `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document`