# Create CloudWatch alarm that sets an instance to standby via SNS/Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

What I am looking to do is set an instance to standby mode when it hits an alarm state. I already have an alarm set up to detect when my instance hits 90% CPU for a while. The alarm currently sends a Slack and text message via SNS calling a Lambda function. I would like to add is to have the instance go into standby mode. The instances are in an autoscaling group.

I found that you can perform this through the CLI using the command :

```
aws autoscaling enter-standby --instance-ids i-66b4f7d5be234234234 --auto-scaling-group-name my-asg --should-decrement-desired-capacity
```

You can also do this with boto3 :

```
    response = client.enter_standby(
        InstanceIds=[
            'string',
        ],
        AutoScalingGroupName='string',
        ShouldDecrementDesiredCapacity=True|False
    )
```

I assume I need to write another Lambda function that will be triggered by SNS that will use the boto3 code to do this?

Is there a better/easier way before I start?

I already have the InstanceId passed into the event to the Lambda so I will have to add the ASG name in the event.

Is there a way to get the ASG name in the Lambda function when I already have the Instance ID? Then I do not have to pass it in with the event.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, here is what I came up with for the Lambda function (in Python) :

```
# Puts the instance in the standby mode which takes it off the load balancer
#   and a replacement unit is spun up to take its place
#

import json
import boto3

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
asg_client = boto3.client('autoscaling')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Get the id from the event JSON
    msg = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
    msg_json = json.loads(msg)
    id = msg_json['Trigger']['Dimensions'][0]['value']
    print("Instance id is " + str(id))

    # Capture all the info about the instance so we can extract the ASG name later
    response = ec2_client.describe_instances(
        Filters=[
            {
                'Name': 'instance-id',
                'Values': [str(id)]
            },
        ],
    )

    # Get the ASG name from the response JSON
    #autoscaling_name = response['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['Tags'][1]['Value']
    tags = response['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['Tags']
    autoscaling_name = next(t["Value"] for t in tags if t["Key"] == "aws:autoscaling:groupName")
    print("Autoscaling name is - " + str(autoscaling_name))

    # Put the instance in standby
    response = asg_client.enter_standby(
        InstanceIds=[
            str(id),
        ],
        AutoScalingGroupName=str(autoscaling_name),
        ShouldDecrementDesiredCapacity=False
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question has a couple sub-parts, so I'll try to answer them in order:

> I assume I need to write another Lambda function that will be triggered by SNS that will use the boto3 code to do this?

You don't **need** to, you could overload your existing function. I could see a valid argument for either separate functions (separation of concerns) or one function (since "reacting to CPU hitting 90%" is basically "one thing").

> Is there a better/easier way before I start?

I don't know of any other way you could do it, other than Cloudwatch -> SNS -> Lambda.

> Is there a way to get the ASG name in the Lambda function when I already have the Instance ID?

Yes, [see this question for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42161300/determine-if-instance-is-a-part-of-some-autoscaling-group-in-aws). It's up to you whether it looks like doing it in the Lambda or passing an additional parameter is the cleaner option.